# Swamp/dead-end pruning in non-grid maps

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, path-finding, pruning

Are there any existing algorithms for finding and avoiding problematic areas ([swamps](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cts=1331274334722&sqi=2&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fleibniz.cs.huji.ac.il%2Ftr%2F1188.pdf&ei=W6JZT7LbB8W_tgePxI2GDA&usg=AFQjCNGr9GJ2U_EcJ1U2Cmxgy9sfgnAlJg), [dead-ends](http://www.ru.is/faculty/yngvi/pdf/BjornssonH06.pdf)) in pathfinding when using non-grid maps? There are plenty available for grids that either avoid these areas or pseudo-avoid these areas by way of [jump point recursion](http://aigamedev.com/open/tutorial/symmetry-in-pathfinding/), etc., but I have yet to find anything useful for quadtrees, navigational meshes, or other non-uniform maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dead-end detection and Swamps are not grid specific. They're just evaluated on grid maps.

Comment: The following article might also be of interest: [Thomas Young, Optimizing Points of Visibility, Game Programming Gems II, 2001]

It details a pruning technique for visibility graphs which is similar to Jump Points. It's unclear to me just now if it could be adapted to Nav Meshes however.

Answer (score 0):

Such a thing probably does exist - hundreds of path finding and motion planning papers are published every year, but I think you need to ask yourself a bigger question - why would you want to do this?

The idea of going to a nav-mesh or sparse grid representation is to reduce the time required to find a solution by reducing the number of nodes in the graph. If your search is too slow, simply prune the number of nodes and edges in your graph. By manually removing any dead ends from the search offline before you even start, you'll reduce the overhead for every search.

If, even after you have pruned your graph, search is still to slow *and* you can tolerate approximate solutions to search problems, consider using [Weighted A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a#Weighted_A.2A), where you replan decreasing the inflation factor until you do have the optimal cost.

Planning algorithms are full of compromises, just make sure you understand what the pros and cons are for whatever you choose to do.

One final suggestion, make sure that you have correctly implemented the primitives in the planner you are using - algorithms like A* depend on having correctly implemented priority queues, in particular make sure that *decrease-key* is O(log n) or [better](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29).

Comment: I'm using quadtrees for a game I'm working on; I use them for both pathfinding and for collision tests. I'd like to find an algorithm for avoiding dead-ends and swamps because this can be done online to improve performance in a map that's created during play; the maps are randomly generated, so I cannot manually optimize them for pathfinding. What I can do, however, is make the map generation optimal and then speed up pathfinding by avoiding problematic areas as they are detected during execution.